# What is the difference between np.float64 and np.double?

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I tried running the following code to find out the difference between `float64` and `double` in `numpy`. The result is interesting as type double takes almost double the time compared with time taken for multiplication with `float64`. Need some light on this.

```
import time
import numpy as np

datalen = 100000
times = 10000

a = np.random.rand(datalen)
b = np.random.rand(datalen)

da = np.float64(a)
db = np.float64(a)

dda = np.double(a)
ddb = np.double(b)

tic = time.time()
for k in range(times):
    dd = dda * ddb
toc = time.time()
print (toc - tic), 'time taken for double'

tic = time.time()
for k in range(times):
    d = da * db
toc = time.time()
print (toc - tic), 'time taken for float64'
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you're comparing apples with oranges.

The first bench is basically `a * b` but the second `a * a`.

I suspect much less cache misses for the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that error in the code. Thank you for pointing it out. When I keep it a * b for both cases, time taken are same. Thank you.

Comment: Cache misses maybe, but more likely is optimized squaring algorithm in numpy.  Squaring can be done in half the time as general multiplication.  Whether using shift and add gradeschool or Karatsuba or other methods, some nice properties allow simplification.  Granted if it's going straight to hardware, unclear if such optimization is happening.

Answer (score 10):

```
import numpy as np
np.double is np.float64 # returns True
```

In theory both should be same.

Comment: That is what I expected. But time taken is almost double.

Answer (score 7):

Many array operations are typically limited only by the time it takes to load the array elements from the RAM into your cache.

So you'd expect the operation to be faster if the size of each value is smaller or you don't need to load so many elements into your cache.

That's why your timings were different: `np.float64` and `np.double` don't actually make copies, so in the first case the arrays are identical while they are not in the second case:

```
>>> da is db
True

>>> dda is ddb
False
```

So the first case can be optimized because you don't need to load values from two arrays but only from one. Thus doubling the bandwith.

However there's another thing to consider: `np.float64` and `np.double` should be identical on most machines but that's not garantueed. `np.float64` is a fixed-sized float value (always 64bit) while `np.double` depends on the machine and/or compiler. On most machines `double`s are `64bit` but that's not always garantueed! So you might have speed differences if your `double` and `float64` are of different widths:

```
>>> np.double(10).itemsize
8
>>> np.float64(10).itemsize
8
>>> np.float64 is np.double
True
```

Comment: `da is db` returns _true_ because of a coding bug... it's in the line: `db = np.float64(a)`...