# Why can't I get this Runge-Kutta solver to converge as the time step decreases?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, numerical-methods, ode

For reasons, I need to implement the Runge-Kutta4 method in PyTorch (so no, I'm not going to use `scipy.odeint`). I tried and I get weird results on the simplest test case, solving x'=x with x(0)=1 (analytical solution: x=exp(t)). Basically, as I reduce the time step, I cannot get the numerical error to go down. I'm able to do it with a simpler Euler method, but not with the Runge-Kutta 4 method, which makes me suspect some floating point issue here (maybe I'm missing some hidden conversion from double precision to single)?

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Euler(f, IC, time_grid):
    y0 = torch.tensor([IC])
    time_grid = time_grid.to(y0[0])
    values = y0

    for i in range(0, time_grid.shape[0] - 1):
        t_i = time_grid[i]
        t_next = time_grid[i+1]
        y_i = values[i]
        dt = t_next - t_i
        dy = f(t_i, y_i) * dt
        y_next = y_i + dy
        y_next = y_next.unsqueeze(0)
        values = torch.cat((values, y_next), dim=0)

    return values

def RungeKutta4(f, IC, time_grid):

    y0 = torch.tensor([IC])
    time_grid = time_grid.to(y0[0])
    values = y0

    for i in range(0, time_grid.shape[0] - 1):
        t_i = time_grid[i]
        t_next = time_grid[i+1]
        y_i = values[i]
        dt = t_next - t_i
        dtd2 = 0.5 * dt
        f1 = f(t_i, y_i)
        f2 = f(t_i + dtd2, y_i + dtd2 * f1)
        f3 = f(t_i + dtd2, y_i + dtd2 * f2)
        f4 = f(t_next, y_i + dt * f3)
        dy = 1/6 * dt * (f1 + 2 * (f2 + f3) +f4)
        y_next = y_i + dy
        y_next = y_next.unsqueeze(0)
        values = torch.cat((values, y_next), dim=0)

    return values

# differential equation
def f(T, X):
    return X 

# initial condition
IC = 1.

# integration interval
def integration_interval(steps, ND=1):
    return torch.linspace(0, ND, steps)

# analytical solution
def analytical_solution(t_range):
    return np.exp(t_range)

# test a numerical method
def test_method(method, t_range, analytical_solution):
    numerical_solution = method(f, IC, t_range)
    L_inf_err = torch.dist(numerical_solution, analytical_solution, float('inf'))
    return L_inf_err


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Euler_error = np.array([0.,0.,0.])
    RungeKutta4_error = np.array([0.,0.,0.])
    indices = np.arange(1, Euler_error.shape[0]+1)
    n_steps = np.power(10, indices)
    for i, n in np.ndenumerate(n_steps):
        t_range = integration_interval(steps=n)
        solution = analytical_solution(t_range)
        Euler_error[i] = test_method(Euler, t_range, solution).numpy()
        RungeKutta4_error[i] = test_method(RungeKutta4, t_range, solution).numpy()

    plots_path = "./plots"
    a = plt.figure()
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.plot(n_steps, Euler_error, label="Euler error", linestyle='-')
    plt.plot(n_steps, RungeKutta4_error, label="RungeKutta 4 error", linestyle='-.')
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(plots_path + "/errors.png")
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, the Euler method converges (slowly, as expected of a first order method). However, the Runge-Kutta4 method *does not* converge as the time step gets smaller and smaller. The error goes down initially, and then up again. What's the issue here?

Comment: Does the `torch` library default to single precision 32bit floats? This should not be a code error, as then the error level for RK4 would not be this low. But the slopes are too low. // What does `time_grid = time_grid.to(y0[0])` do?

Comment: @LutzLehmann the single precision float was exactly the issue here! Using `np.float64` for all `numpy` float arrays and `torch.float64` for all `torch` tensors gave me the required accuracy. If you write an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll answer the question myself.

Comment: Do it, you did the work and tested it, I only presented a most likely hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is indeed a floating point precision issue. `torch` defaults to single precision, so once the [truncation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_error) becomes small enough, the total error is basically determined by the [roundoff error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error), and reducing the truncation error further by increasing the number of steps <=> decreasing the time step doesn't lead to any decrease in the total error.

To fix this, we need to enforce double precision 64bit floats for all floating point `torch` tensors and `numpy` arrays. Note that the right way to do this is to use respectively `torch.float64` and `np.float64` rather than, e.g., `torch.double` and `np.double`, because [the former are fixed-sized float values,  (always 64bit) while the latter depend on the machine and/or compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43682433/1711271). Here's the fixed code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Euler(f, IC, time_grid):

    y0 = torch.tensor([IC], dtype=torch.float64)
    time_grid = time_grid.to(y0[0])
    values = y0

    for i in range(0, time_grid.shape[0] - 1):
        t_i = time_grid[i]
        t_next = time_grid[i+1]
        y_i = values[i]
        dt = t_next - t_i
        dy = f(t_i, y_i) * dt
        y_next = y_i + dy
        y_next = y_next.unsqueeze(0)
        values = torch.cat((values, y_next), dim=0)

    return values

def RungeKutta4(f, IC, time_grid):

    y0 = torch.tensor([IC], dtype=torch.float64)
    time_grid = time_grid.to(y0[0])
    values = y0

    for i in range(0, time_grid.shape[0] - 1):
        t_i = time_grid[i]
        t_next = time_grid[i+1]
        y_i = values[i]
        dt = t_next - t_i
        dtd2 = 0.5 * dt
        f1 = f(t_i, y_i)
        f2 = f(t_i + dtd2, y_i + dtd2 * f1)
        f3 = f(t_i + dtd2, y_i + dtd2 * f2)
        f4 = f(t_next, y_i + dt * f3)
        dy = 1/6 * dt * (f1 + 2 * (f2 + f3) +f4)
        y_next = y_i + dy
        y_next = y_next.unsqueeze(0)
        values = torch.cat((values, y_next), dim=0)

    return values

    # differential equation
def f(T, X):
    return X 

# initial condition
IC = 1.

# integration interval
def integration_interval(steps, ND=1):
    return torch.linspace(0, ND, steps, dtype=torch.float64)

# analytical solution
def analytical_solution(t_range):
    return np.exp(t_range, dtype=np.float64)

# test a numerical method
def test_method(method, t_range, analytical_solution):
    numerical_solution = method(f, IC, t_range)
    L_inf_err = torch.dist(numerical_solution, analytical_solution, float('inf'))
    return L_inf_err


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Euler_error = np.array([0.,0.,0.], dtype=np.float64)
    RungeKutta4_error = np.array([0.,0.,0.], dtype=np.float64)
    indices = np.arange(1, Euler_error.shape[0]+1)
    n_steps = np.power(10, indices)
    for i, n in np.ndenumerate(n_steps):
        t_range = integration_interval(steps=n)
        solution = analytical_solution(t_range)
        Euler_error[i] = test_method(Euler, t_range, solution).numpy()
        RungeKutta4_error[i] = test_method(RungeKutta4, t_range, solution).numpy()

    plots_path = "./plots"
    a = plt.figure()
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.plot(n_steps, Euler_error, label="Euler error", linestyle='-')
    plt.plot(n_steps, RungeKutta4_error, label="RungeKutta 4 error", linestyle='-.')
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(plots_path + "/errors.png")
```

Result:

[image]

Now, as we decrease the time step, the error of the RungeKutta4 approximation decreases with the correct rate.

Comment: This now also has the expected slopes. If you continue the subdivision number to 10^5, you should also recover the V shape of the error, with the minimum probably at the displayed level for 10^3. To get the V shape for the Euler method, you would have to continue to 10^12, as the minimum is expected at 10^8. Only do that if you implement this experiment in a compiled language (or "pure" cython or at least use some JIT tool like numba), else the run time will be very long, explicit python loops are slow.